# LPMetadataProvider/LinkPresentation: how to use custom image/icon on Slack/WhatsApp, ...?

Tags: swift

I followed the tutorial here (https://richkolasa.netlify.app/posts/2019/07/composing-rich-link-previews-using-linkpresentation-in-swift/) - I try to share a URL with custom preview image.

It works that "my" image is shown in the share sheet preview, everything also works when sharing it with iMessage. But e.g. WhatsApp and Slack don't work, they show the "default" preview image.

This kind of makes sense to me, as how should they know the Apple specific stuff; nevertheless I'm curious if there's a way to change that for 3rd party apps as well as it's confusing this way for the user: the preview shows something different as is finally shared.

The full ViewController code:

```
import LinkPresentation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIActivityItemSource {
    var metadata: LPLinkMetadata?

    // The placeholder the share sheet will use while metadata loads
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return "Giant Panda!!!!!!"
    }

    // The item we want the user to act on.
    // In this case, it's the URL to the Wikipedia page
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        return self.metadata?.url
    }

    // The metadata we want the system to represent as a rich link
    func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
        return self.metadata
    }

    @IBAction func shareTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_panda")!
        LPMetadataProvider().startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { linkMetadata, _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                LPMetadataProvider().startFetchingMetadata(for: URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/Lightmatter_panda.jpg")!) { imageMetadata, _ in
                    linkMetadata?.imageProvider = imageMetadata?.imageProvider
                    linkMetadata?.iconProvider = imageMetadata?.imageProvider
                    self.metadata = linkMetadata
                    let activityVc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self], applicationActivities: nil)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.present(activityVc, animated: true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about the Open Graph Metadata. All the apps like WhatsApp, Facebook honours it and render the links accordingly.

With the LinkPresentation framework, you can do the following:

1. Fetch Open graph metadata of any link and present the link in your app richly.
2. Pass the metadata to Native Share Screen to render the metadata immediately without fetching.

If you are not the owner of the link and it doesn't have metadata, you cannot add yourself.

If you are the owner of the link, the first thing you should do is add the metadata. It will automatically get rendered in apps like whatsapp.

Attaching sample metadata here.

```
<HTML>
<head>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Colby Fayock" />
<meta property=“og:title” content=“Anyone Can Map! Inspiration and an introduction to the world of mapping - Colby Fayock" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Chef Gusteau was a visionary who created food experiences for the world to enjoy. How can we take his lessons and apply them to the world of…" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.colbyfayock.com/2020/03/anyone-can-map-inspiration-and-an-introduction-to-the-world-of-mapping/" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.colbyfayock.com" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Coding" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="Coding" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://res.cloudinary.com/fay/image/upload/w_1280,h_640,c_fill,q_auto,f_auto/w_860,c_fit,co_rgb:232129,g_west,x_80,y_-60,l_text:Source%20Sans%20Pro_70_line_spacing_-10_semibold:Anyone%20Can%20Map!%20Inspiration%20and%20an%20introduction%20to%20the%20world%20of%20mapping/blog-social-card-1.1" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://res.cloudinary.com/fay/image/upload/w_1280,h_640,c_fill,q_auto,f_auto/w_860,c_fit,co_rgb:232129,g_west,x_80,y_-60,l_text:Source%20Sans%20Pro_70_line_spacing_-10_semibold:Anyone%20Can%20Map!%20Inspiration%20and%20an%20introduction%20to%20the%20world%20of%20mapping/blog-social-card-1.1" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1280" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="640" />
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta property="twitter:image" content="https://res.cloudinary.com/fay/image/upload/w_1280,h_640,c_fill,q_auto,f_auto/w_860,c_fit,co_rgb:232129,g_west,x_80,y_-60,l_text:Source%20Sans%20Pro_70_line_spacing_-10_semibold:Anyone%20Can%20Map!%20Inspiration%20and%20an%20introduction%20to%20the%20world%20of%20mapping/blog-social-card-1.1" />
<meta property="twitter:site" content="@colbyfayock" />
</head>
</HTML>
```